# tooltip text is out of block in Chrome

Tags: highcharts

I'm using Highcharts on my site and I have a problem with tooltip text in Chrome - it is out of the box (see [tooltip-error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DLii.png))

It works in other browsers.
Who knows what it could be?

Comment: I love these false taglines in brackets after the title. "Put on hold as Chrome by Mitchell Baker and Steve Ballmer"...

Comment: It seems I found the solution: add the following to tooltip "useHTML: true". It works.

Comment: ignvar - do the community a favor and post the solution to your problem as an answer. The point of this place is ultimately to build a database of problems and solutions

Answer (score 1):

It seems I found the solution: add the following to tooltip "useHTML: true". It works now.